# Failed to build the docker image - npm ERR! sharp@0.30.7 install

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Now I've some issues while building the docker image. It worked before but now it stopped to work.

Here is my DockerFile.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM node:14.17.5
ENV NODE_ENV=development

#ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/passio.npm-global
#ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/node/passio.npm-global/bin


RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y sudo \
  && apt-get install -y systemd \
  && apt-get install -y dbus-user-session

# RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' docker
# RUN adduser docker sudo
# RUN echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

# USER docker


# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /home/docker/passio
# RUN chown docker /home/docker/passio
WORKDIR /home/docker/passio

RUN npm config rm proxy
RUN npm config rm https-proxy --tried removing npm proxy


COPY package.json .
# COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . ./


# RUN sudo /etc/init.d/dbus start

RUN node systemd install
RUN node systemd enable

# RUN node db/sync
# RUN node browserify --reset

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["npm", "run", "restart" ]
```

When I run the command to build the docker image - `docker build -t passio:dev . --no-cache`.

I get the following error.

```
#16 123.6 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
#16 123.6 npm ERR! errno 1
#16 123.7 npm ERR! sharp@0.30.7 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
#16 123.7 npm ERR! Exit status 1
#16 123.7 npm ERR! 
#16 123.7 npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.30.7 install script.
#16 123.7 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
#16 123.7 
#16 123.7 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#16 123.7 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-11-25T15_08_51_150Z-debug.log
```

I tried to upgraded the node version from `14.17.5` to `16` and inserted the command to install the `sharp` package into the DockerFile like `Run npm install sharp` but neither solves the problem.

Is there anything I'm missing or anything to update?

Please help me.

Comment: What does the error look like in the complete log referenced in the error message above?